# about a regex for match advance page range

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex to match a page range, but more complicated!

I need to match the following string:

```
1-20 : from No.1 page to No.20, 
1-20x2: from No.1 to No.20 and step is 2, so it'll print 10 pages
1-20a2: from No.1 to No.20, every 2 page printed to 1 paper
1-20x2a2:
1-20a2x3:
1,3-20a2x3,
1-20a2x3,30-35x2
1-20x3a2,30-25a2
```

I have write a regex:

```
^([0-9]*|[0-9]*-[1-9][0-9]*(x[1-9][0-9]*)?(a[1-9][0-9]*)?)(,([0-9]*|[0-9]*-[1-9][0-9]*(x[1-9][0-9]*)?(a[1-9][0-9]*)?))*$
```

which can match almost every situation, but the order of "x" and "a" cannot be changed,

So please help me to fix it! thank you !

Comment: With a situation like this, the best thing to do is to build up a regular expression from component parts.  Look at the mail address parser from one of the editions of "Mastering Regular Expressions," by Jeffrey Friedl. I think it appears in the second edition.

Comment: what language do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Without verifying repeated x's and a's:

```
(?:(\d+)(,\d+)?-(\d+)([ax]\d+)?([ax]\d+)?)+
```

Thought a little help from the programming language could greatly simplify this.